# Why "not" operator is faster than regular condition in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading one article about list comprehensions and it mentions that list comprehensions are faster than regular and nested for loops. And while reading that article it mentions that this statement

```
  if expression % 2 == 0:
```

slower than

```
  if not expression % 2:
```

Can anybody explain reason behind this? Even I am solving trees problems and there is in recursion I am using **not root** kind of arguments. So that would be grateful if anybody can help.

Link to article: https://switowski.com/blog/for-loop-vs-list-comprehension
Here is short implementation, thanks to @Ted

```
>>> MILLION_NUMBERS = list(range(1_000_000))
>>> def for_loop():
...     output = []
...     for element in MILLION_NUMBERS:
...         if not element % 2:
...             output.append(element)
...     return output
... 
>>> def for_loop2():
...     output = []
...     for element in MILLION_NUMBERS:
...         if element % 2 == 0:
...             output.append(element)
...     return output
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=for_loop, number=100)
6.254316797000001
>>> timeit.timeit(stmt=for_loop2, number=100)
7.362754617999997
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is python 3. Yes according to author as list comprehension makes difference this also makes difference. Yes author confirm that this is case, he also mentioned he will publish article which I checked he still didn't. About all versions I don't know. I believe it's for all python implementations.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Question updated with link.

Comment: Hey @TedKleinBergman can you share your experiment here so everybody can see that including me? Because I seen such things at many articles!

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Can I take that code and update my question, if you don't mind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the disassembler on both the cases, you'll find:

> if expression % 2 == 0:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_MODULO
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
              8 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             10 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20
```

> if not expression % 2:

```
2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              4 BINARY_MODULO
              6 POP_JUMP_IF_TRUE        16
```

The above example has to do two more operations to determine if the value is zero.
This was probably the basis the book author said that. In reality this barely makes any difference, and can vastly differ across implementations of python.
You can also use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module to time it!

```
>>> timeit.timeit('5 % 2 == 0', number=10**7)
0.47088638799323235
>>> timeit.timeit('not 5 % 2', number=10**7)
0.1560280679987045
```

which would show you the second one is almost 3x faster than the first one.

Comment: Just curious how you use disassembler? Can you share code for same?

Comment: @yashChoksi https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @yashChoksi Usually you do not really have to worry about such small implementation details cause the [compiler is smarter than you](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/27/smarter-than-compiler/)

Comment: @Anunay That's usually true for statically typed and compiled languages. It's not really true for Python

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I mean Python kinda "compiles" to bytecode (please don't kill me), I just wanted to share that as a general Programming idea. :P

Comment: @Anunay CPython compiles to bytecode, but does very little in the way of optimising the bytecode. It avoids creating tuples for code like `a,b = b,a` but doesn't go much beyond things like that, and given that operators like `%` and `==` can be overloaded to do arbitrary things, there is not much scope for Python bytecode to be optimised without making assumptions that the compiler cannot safely make by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The principle reason is that Python does not know that `expression` is an integer; potentially, it could be an object which overrides operators, so `expression % 2 == 0` could mean calling `expression.__mod__(2).__eq__(0).__bool__()` (or `.__len__()`).

I'm not sure if Python actually calls them or optimises them away for integers, but either way it has to look them up, each time through the loop. Each of those method look-ups takes a tiny bit of time.

Meanwhile, `not expression % 2` could at most be `expression.__mod__(2).__bool__()` (or `.__len__()`) — the look-up of `==` is skipped (there is no override for `not`).